# xcode can't show version tree but commit and everything works just fine

Tags: xcode, svn

I have a svn server installed in my local machine and configured xcode to use it. I can do import, checkout, commit etc, but can't see the version tree in SCM tab in any file's Info window.

[image: it shows the current revision though]

Is there anything else I need to set up to see the versions?

Answer (score 1):

Still not got answers? Did you try 'svn log' in command line?

Comment: Hey, I got it working on another port. Just can't work on the default port. How did you find this post anyway? :)